# Angular $scope property undefined

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, jasmine

I'm trying to set the `$scope.sang` property to an instance of `SangService` in a directive. Problem is, it doesn't appear to be getting set.

### The Setup

#### sang-player.directive.js:

```
angular.module('sang').directive('sangPlayer', [
  'SangService',
  function(SangService) {
    return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      scope: true,
      link: function(scope, _elem, attr) {
        window.console.log('link');
        scope.sang = SangService.$new();
      }
    };
  }]);
```

#### sang-player.directive.spec.js:

```
describe('The Sang Directive', function() {
  var compile, scope, element, sang;

  beforeEach(function() {
    sang = jasmine.createSpyObj('sang',
      ['play', 'pause', 'playPause', 'previous', 'next', 'seek']);

    module(function($provide) {
      $provide.value('Sang', sang);
    });

    inject(function($compile, $rootScope) {
      compile = $compile;
      scope = $rootScope.$new();
      element = getCompiledElement();
    });
  });

  function getCompiledElement() {
    var element = angular.element('<div sang-player></div>');
    var compiledElement = compile(element)(scope);
    scope.$digest();
    return compiledElement;
  }

  it('creates a scope.sang object', function() {
    expect(scope.sang).toBeDefined();
    expect(typeof scope.sang).toBe('object');
  });
});
```

#### Output from failed Jasmine spec run:

```
 The Sang Directive
 X creates a scope.sang object
   Expected undefined to be defined. (1)
   Expected 'undefined' to be 'object'. (2)
```

Not sure why there's no output from the `link` callback. I would expect this to get called within `compile(element)(scope)` or `scope.$digest()`.

### The Deets

- Angular 1.4.1
- Jasmine 2.4.1
- grunt-contrib-jasmine 0.9.1
- The full project repo lives [here](https://github.com/acobster/sang) if you want to tinker.

Comment: Try using `scope = compiledElement.isolateScope();` after scope.$digest();

Comment: Looks like you don't register the module containing the directive in your test? This would explain the lack of link..

Comment: @GBa the module gets registered in my main SangService.js file (not included here), and grunt-contrib-jasmine concatenates these files before each run.